# Access denied for anonymous users clicking on download link

Tags: display-suite, files

I have a content type with a file field that has been formatted by display suite. I set the display suite formatter to download link.

This works fine for users who are logged in, but anonymous users get the access denied page. Is there some permission settings or file folder permission settings I need to deal with?
Accessing the raw file URL is possible for anonymous users though.

The formatter makes the link become something like this: http://example.com/file/980/download?token=OBVqG5D1va06NDH2_BcgF0vqwVhhNHsnNYcHYHGQ5_g

Comment: Is it on a private filesystem? How did you configured your field? Was it OK before you started to use Display Suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the file entity module and the latest stable version has the patch for this issue committed to it. If you had encountered this issue in the past, update file entity to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permission issue for anonymous user. Check the permission section. Also give your file folder the required permissions, where the files are being uploaded.

Comment: I went through all the permissions for anonymous users and all the relevant ones were enabled. After that I just enabled all permissions for anonymous users just to check and that did not work either.

Comment: Also, anonymous users are able to access the file folder as the absolute url to the file allows them to access the file.

Comment: Try this after removing display suite, if it works fine then there would be some issue in formatting.

Comment: After further investigation, I realised it's not an issue with Display Suite per se but with the File Entity module. The download link formatter was introduced by the File Entity module. Another weird thing is that this issue is not consistently repeatable. I have tested the download link across a number of PCs and it works for some and not for others. I cannot pinpoint the common denominator for those PCs whereby the download links did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get anywhere with this?  I wonder if it's related to jesss' answer over here: https://drupal.org/node/2136453

"Download tokens work for the first anonymous user -- any anons coming after get the 403 error."